# Don't prented to be pretty

Tags: grammar

If someone pretend to be pretty, she thinks to herself as princess. Someone agree and other disagree and get pissed off at pretending.
Can I say to her " Don't pretend to be pretty!" "It's cheese."
or "Stop being that pretty" All is correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Don't pretend to be pretty** is perfectly grammatical. Of course you will be thought boorishly rude, but your grammar will be esteemed.

**It's cheese** is perfectly grammatical though completely meaningless to me except in reference to cheddar, Roquefort, Brie, *etc*.

**Stop being that pretty** is also grammatical but nonsensical.

Comment: "Stop being that pretty" may be nonsensical, but the similar, "Stop **acting so** pretty" would be sensible, grammatical, and likely convey the intended meaning. Also, while I agree that "It's cheese" doesn't make much sense, it's worth pointing out that similar grammatical structures exist and they express a similar sentiment (such as "It's horsefeathers," "It's baloney," "It's smoke-and-mirrors," "It's fluff", etc.)

Comment: **Stop acting so pretty** does not convey the seemingly intended notion that the person commanded is not pretty. That would be better expressed as **Stop acting as though you are pretty.** Locutions like **It's baloney** might in context convey that the person addressed is not pretty, but do not convey any command.  The first option presented seems to be the only one that, grammatically, completely, and cogently, represents a command directed at someone whom the speaker does not consider pretty.

Comment: I agree that "Stop acting as though you are pretty" is an even better way to say it. My comment wasn't intended to disagree with your answer, but to help give the OP (and other learners) a little extra information.

Comment: JR You are correct. My answer was curt. Thank you for pointing that out.  I think I got distracted by contemplating the many ways to construe "correct." I was trying to imply that being grammatical does not entail that a statement is wise, polite, realistic, or even comprehensible.

Comment: When a question on ELL begins with something like: _If someone pretend to be pretty, she thinks to herself as princess_ (instead of the more grammatically correct: _If someone **pretends** to be pretty, she thinks **of** herself as **a** princess_), then I look at the proposed alternatives (such as "It's cheese") and try to figure out what similar constructs a learner might have heard that led them to believe that something might be a valid alternative, even though it might strike us native speakers as quite out-of-place.